# Hiding multiple spans in HTML Table Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’m having trouble hiding a `<span>` in a table row. I want a bootstrap badge call “ExpandDetail” to click on a function and then hide itself, then show another `<span>` named “CollapseDetail” in the same `<tr>`. Note that both `<span>` use the bootstrap “badge” class. The calling element can hide itself just fine, but I can’t find the associated span in the `<tr>` to hide it. Here’s a demo:

```
<tr>
    <td>12345
       <span id="ExpandDetail" style="cursor: pointer;" class="badge" onclick="return openDetail(this, ‘1’);">ABC 123</span> 
        <span id="CollapseDetail" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: hidden" class="badge" onclick="return closeDetail(this, ‘1’);">ABC 123 </span>
     </td>
     <td>$100.00</td>
     <td>$200.00</td>
</tr>

function openDetail(t, ID) {
    // Hides the calling <span> ExpandDetail just fine
    $(t).hide();
    // Need to show the <span> named  CollapseDetail
}

function closeDetail(t, ID){
    // Hides the calling <span> closeDetail just fine
    $(t).hide();

    // Need to show the <span> named ExpandDetail
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No need for separate functions. Just toggle the sibling span

```
function toggleDetail(t, ID){

   $(t).hide().siblings('.badge').show();

   // or use `toggle()` on both

   $(t).parent().find('.badge').toggle();
}
```

Note that css `visibility` is not controlled by hide() or show()

Comment: $(t).hide().siblings('.badge').show(); will hide the "ExpandDetail" detail .badge class but it does not show the "CollapseDetail" span class which is not visible by default. Any ideas?

Comment: see last note about `visibility` . try `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`